# Adding Records to Table from Template Field Checkbox selection and Gridview Boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently building a Attendance Register System in ASP.Net using C#.
The system has a database including these Sql tables;

```
Attendance Table
AttendanceID
Present (boolean type)
StudentID

Student Table
StudentID
StudentName
CourseID

Course Table
CourseID
CourseName
```

I have populated a dropdownlist with the Course Table and based on the selected `CourseID` in the dropdownlist a gridview is populated from the student table where the `studentID` and `StudentName` is displayed with the same `CourseID` that is selected in the dropdownlist. This works fine.

The Attendance Table does not contain any records untill the register has been taken and records are added.

Now for the tricky bit, the gridivew displays all the `StudentID` which have the same `CourseID` based on the `CourseID` selected in the dropdownlist. The gridview also has a template field with a checkbox, this allows the user to check the checkbox if the student is present.

There is a `SaveAttendance` Button on the page. Once the user clicks the `SaveAttendance` button, I want to add all the `StudentID`'s displayed in the gridview along with adding the status of the checkboxes (weather they are checked or not) into the Attendance table  fields `StudentID` and Present respectively. 
Need help as soon as possible, any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I may be blind when i read you question. Good formatting is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statement to access any control in a gridView:

```
Control control = gridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].FindControl(controlID);
```

Then you can cast it to its right type and get its properties values:

```
Boolean checked = ((CheckBox) control).Checked;
```

---

I believe you need to read some tutorials:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548005.aspx

Comment: I take thats the code for checking each of the checkboxes in the gridview? How do I go about populating the Attendance Table field StudentID with the StudentID's displayed in the Gridview?

Comment: This does not mean much to me as I am only a beginner with ASP.Net could you explain your answer more clearly please?